# WordPress - Script inside the loop only works once

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've got this script in my header and this piece of code in my index, **inside the post loop**:

```js
  $(function() {
    var score = parseInt($('.post-score').text().trim());
    var color = '#de1d1d';
    if (!isNaN(score)) {
      if (score >= 5) {
        color = '#b84e1f';
      }
      if (score >= 7) {
        color = '#26b81f';
      }
      if (score >= 9) {
        color = '#d9e019';
      }
      if (score >= 10) {
        color = '#0cf';
      }
      $('.post-score').css('color', color);
    }
  });
```

```html
<?php if( in_category( 'reviews') ) : ?>
<div id="post">
  <span class="post-score">
      <?php the_field('customfield'); ?>
  </span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This function changes that custom field text color depending on the number outputted and it is actually working fine, but **just once**. It's only working for the FIRST POST with a review, and not in every post.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery each: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Right now, your code is only looking at the first `.post-score` that it finds.

Edit:  I've got it working for you here on this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8b53j2ah/1/

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Really thank you bro :) I'll accept this answer but I would need some more help. What If I wanted that output (.post-score) to change the background-color of the father div (#post)? I've been reading the API and tried so, but it's not working :S I tried to change a bit that code you gave me, but it seems it can't work changing another element.

Comment: You could use '.parent()' to modify the containing div.  I've updated the fiddle so you can see how it works:  https://jsfiddle.net/8b53j2ah/2/

You should also consider @JWhy's method, unless the colors are changing with some kind of user action, this sounds like something that should be pre-processed with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

That JQuery code is likely only executed once. But you can achieve the same with PHP.

```html
<?php if( in_category( 'reviews') ) :
    $score = get_field('customfield');
    $score_color = '';
    if($score >= 5 && $score < 7) $score_color = 'b84e1f';
      elseif($score >= 7 && $score < 9) $score_color = '26b81f';
      elseif($score >= 9  && $score < 10) $score_color = 'd9e019';
      elseif($score >= 10) $score_color = '0cf';
?>
<div id="post">
  <span class="post-score" style="color: #<?php echo $score_color; ?>">
      <?php the_field('customfield'); ?>
  </span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You may want to use seperate CSS classes instead of the style-attribute.

Comment: First time it didn't work. Then I realized that your code is saying "if $score is bigger than 5, use this color" but the number, if it's 8 for example, will also be higher than 5. So it was always using the first code. I improved it like this and now it's working: `elseif($score >= 5 && $score < 7)`. Now it will always use the correct number. 
New question (I also summon you @AdamKonieska ): Would it be better to use PHP or jQuery? Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: My fault, I should've tested it. I personally feel uncomfortable with having design-logic in server side code, thus I'd tend to let PHP choose the CSS classes according to the scores. Information such as color is contained in the classes. The usage of JQuery seems do-able as well, but I think for such an easy task (assigning color to a CSS element) you shouldn't force users to have JS enabled.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I did. Thank you bro!

Answer (score 0):

you could set up a function including the above javascript and then run it under the onchange attribute. Eg. onchange="function()"